# WordPress Multisite Subdomain showing error 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, multisite

here is situation i'm experiencing setting up a wordpress multisite subdomain, after setting it up, changing the necceassary edit at wp-config. php and the .htaccess files, the main site is working directly and the subdomain site is showing error 404.

this is .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Set the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header if it's present
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Redirect /wp-admin to /wp-admin/ with a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

# If the request is for a valid file or directory, do not rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# For subdomains, pass the request to the subdomain's index.php file
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```